# asymmetric encryption with rekeying in an untrusted environment

Tags: encryption, public-key

Alice can retrieve asymmetric encrypted messages (let's call one of them C<sub>1</sub> and the Message itself M) for her from an untrusted environment (let's call it Eve). She owns her private key K<sub>1</sub> and has published her public key P<sub>1</sub>. Bob is just like Alice and uses Eve's platform. He owns his private key K<sub>2</sub> and his published public key P<sub>2</sub>.

Alice now decides to share all her Messages with Bob. Normally she would retrieve each encrypted message C<sub>1</sub>, decrypt it to M using K<sub>1</sub> and encrypt it again to C<sub>2</sub> using P<sub>2</sub>.

However, Alice is in a rush today and doesn't have the time to 'translate' all that messages. She would rather like to create some form of re-encryption key R combining K<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub>. It is important that you cannot calculate K<sub>1</sub> (since it is private for Alice) even when you know R and maybe P<sub>2</sub>. She would then send Eve R and Eve has to translate all possible messages C<sub>1</sub> directly to C<sub>2</sub> without ever finding out M.

Does any asymmetric encryption method exist which provides such a 'rekeying' feature?

Comment: How do you define formally the fact that Alice should not decrypt then reencrypt?

Comment: Alice has neither the time nor the resources to decrypt and reencrypt all her (possibly thousands of) messages. Not sure if that is what you meant?

Comment: I see, but in the theoretical world, there is many ways to define "time" and "resource", it depends how do you define an algorithm (a Turing Machine, A RAM machine). Personally, I don't know any work that point the fact that : The property "The algorithm A is strictly faster than B and C".

Comment: It wasn't my real concern that Alice doasn't want to do the re-encryption. I managed to find out that what I was looking for is called proxy re-encryption and can be done with e.g. Elgamal encryption.